# Desktop tool to batch convert Shapefils to CSV with polygon outline coordinates

Tags: shapefile, csv, data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert .shp to .csv including attributes AND geometry?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/how-to-convert-shp-to-csv-including-attributes-and-geometry)

Is there a desktop tool that would allow me to take dozens of large (300MB) shapefiles and convert them into CSV files?  My goal is to extract just a few chunks of data from them (ID, name, lat/lon list of polygon outline) for loading into a database.

Comment: What database? Is this really the only way to load data into it? Also are you using ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: It will be a MySQL DB, and I am not using ArcGIS Desktop.  

Also, I don't think this is a duplicate.  The question it was redirected to has nothing to do with a desktop tool, and instead deals with Python and SQL scripts.