# Dropping z-value from geometry and transfering it to new field

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, z-value

Having a points shapefile with z values, how do I keep in the geometry only the x,y values? I also want to move the z values to a newly created double field.

Comment: Might be worth having a look here: http://www.faunalia.com/content/transfer-3d-shapefiles-z-values-table-attributes

Answer (score 2):

What about exporting with appended Lat/Lon (Vector -> Geometry-Tools -> Export/Append Geometry Columns), saving as new file ?
If the function is implemented 3D (sorry, I've no idea if) this should give you the required result.
To make shure the z is dropped, you might export the result as CSV, edit and again load as new layer.

Comment: The function doesn't have z support.

Comment: There is an thread which might be helpful:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/how-to-convert-shp-to-csv-including-attributes-and-geometry

Especially the idea to transfer the shp into a database

Answer (score 2):

I used http://converter.mygeodata.eu/ there I can convert a shape file to csv file with xyz or xy values. Edit and again load as new layer.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Extract Z values` which "Extracts z values from geometries into feature attributes."
2. Right-click the layer - Export  - Save Features As and untick "Include z-dimension"