# Importing csv file in QGIS including names and description

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, mmqgis

I'm just getting to learn QGIS. I want to make a map (Google maps) where I can map all our customers from our database. Including names and even better: description, address, telephone, etc. All this data is available in our own database.

So far I managed to import a csv list using Mmqgis. 
Then added another layer with Openlayers
All works fine.

Also tried exporting the .shp as .kml, uploaded it to Dropbox and opened the link in a newly created personal Google Map. Works fine.

But the result is a map with locations. In which step can I include company names, not having to do this by hand...? I tried importing csv files via mmqgis with additional columns for names, etc. but I can't see where this information is stored in the QGIS project/I don't know if it is stored.

Any help is welcome!

Edit:
I found out that I can just import an xlsx file and select the correct columns in the google map creator... 
Edit2: Now I see only Google accounts can edit the map, it would make more sense to use OSM or whatsoever I guess. Any thoughts on this? I'm diving into OSM now, but importing xlsx doesnt seem to be an option as easy as in Google Maps. So first question remains: how to include names/description in QGIS/OSM
Edit3: I'm looking for a solution csv->map including names/descriptions, preferably not Google Maps.

Comment: Ah, wait, I found out that I can just import an xlsx file and select the correct columns in the google map creator...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert .shp to .csv including attributes AND geometry?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/how-to-convert-shp-to-csv-including-attributes-and-geometry)

Comment: I've seen that one, but thats shp to csv. I'm looking for csv->map, via QGIS, mmQGIS, whatsoever... 

Furthermore, now I see only Google accounts can edit the map, it would make more sense to use OSM or whatsoever I guess. Any thoughts on this? I'm diving into OSM now, but importing xlsx doesnt seem to be an option as easy as in Google Maps. So first question remains: how to include names/description in QGIS/OSM

Comment: @Jasper Please included your comments as edits to your original question by clicking on the "edit" button

Comment: I agree with @dassouki that this question needs revising to make clear what is being asked.  I think [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) can offer some valuable advice on how to do that.